# UK Visa application document format

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork

I am inviting my mum to the UK for 2 months and sponsoring her trip fully (tickets, stay, food etc).

Do I need to submit my original bank statement, pay slips, invitation letter to vfs in India or will scanned copies suffice?

Answer (score 5):

The guide to supporting documents https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf states that all documents must be originals and not photocopies.

Comment: Thank you ,these are for person applying visa from India..i wanted to about the documents  i have to send to sponsor herll. For eg my bank statements, invitation  letter , address details etc.

Comment: @Nee The requirement for originals applies to all documents submitted, that is, both the applicant’s personal documents and those of any sponsor.

Answer (score 0):

You need not submit originals, scanned copies are sufficient. I have brought my in-laws last year and I don't remember sending any originals.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Even the invitation letter can be scanned ??

Comment: @Nee You apparently accept VJS's statement that copies were probably accepted in his in-laws' matter. While copies would certainly be easier for you to produce, I'll suggest that despite VJS's experience the UKVI Documents Guide is still in force, and you risk denial on this procedural ground (without regard to the merits of your application) if you send copies.